openzepplin uups upgrade with storage layout change
I had a mapping like this:
mapping(address => MyStruct) private _inventory;

and I want to upgrade the contract so that mapping will change to this
mapping(uint256 => MyNewStruct) private _inventory;

Ofcourse, this changes the storage layout and openzeppelin hardhat upgrade validation rightfully points it out. But here is the question, I have a way to pause the contract, flush the _inventory (I have a counter so I know when it is empty) and then upgrade. Would it then be safe to upgrade ignoring this storage layout change warning?
Am I overlooking any other aspects?

If you flush all your old data, I think it works.
Because storage pointer of mapping is computed by: hash(hash(key), base_slot_of_mapping).
The storage pointer will be kept if you don't change the order of mapping in list variable. Data in solidity are stored as a bytes and will be parsed according your struct, if you flush all data and add new values with new Struct type, I think it can work well.
Btw, some framework won't allow you to upgrade Struct like hardhat, you will need to turn off safe check when upgrade.

Thanks for your very helpful response. I did already go ahead with the flush and upgrade. All works great. Did have to turn-off the storage layout check of oz upgrade plugin.
